# Appium webdriver

Tags: python, appium, webdriver

Я установил библиотеку Appium-Python-Client и при импортировании:
from appium import webdriver PyCharm подчеркивает красным webdriver, у меня уже есть chromedriver в переменной path для работы с selenium, может быть кто то подскажет что мне делать.
я пробовал установить uiautomator2, но фокус не удался

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в следующий раз читай текст ошибки и хотя бы попытайся самостоятельно нагуглить решение

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта Settings - Project (интерпретатор) - Python указан верно? Попробуй в Pycharm установить библиотеку, а то ее не видно